# Linq to SQL return list objects

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have this model that joints two table cars and model. I can only see the data within the model. So if it returns two models it will on only display one record. I am trying to have to return a list of objects?

Model

```
 public class CarsJoinModel
    {
        public Cars Cars { get; set; }
        public Model Model { get; set; }
    }

IQueryable<CarsJoinModel> GetCarsAndModel();
```

`The name Select does not exist in the current context`

```
Model = t.Model 
         .Select(entry => new
         {
         DisplayName = entry,
         Model = entry.
         }).ToList(),
```

`This is working but will I will need this to be a list`

```
Model = t.Model.DisplayName
```

Updated

```
var CarsModel = (from c in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Cars>().Get()
                      join m in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Model>().Get() on c.Id equals m.CarId
                      select new CarsModel 
                      {
                      Car = c,
                      Model = m
                      }
                );



public class CarsModel 
{
    public CarsCars{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Model> Model{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Change `public Model Model { get; set; }` to `public IEnumerable<Model> Models { get; set; }` and `.Select(entry => new` to `.Select(entry => new Model()` as the projection will need to be of `Model` types.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it with using IEnumerable? I would need to change other section of the code

Comment: If you are `trying to have to return a list of objects` and the model is currently not a collection type, then yes you will have to make downstream changes.

Comment: Thanks I updated the with your information when I select the data do I need to cast the result `Model = m`?

Comment: You should almost never need a cast - what is the datatype of `TemplatesAgent.Model`? What is the datatype of `m` (`Model`?) ?

Comment: its a IEnumerable Model type

Comment: So `TemplatesAgent.Model` is `IEnumerable<Model>`? And what is `m`?

Comment: m is just a public class model `public partial class Model: IDatabaseEntity, INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: I have the feeling your model is flawed. What is the relation between car and model?

Comment: Can [edit] the question to include all relevant information?   For example, I have no clue what is inside the Cars type, or the Model type.  Also as Paul pointed out, we can't determine what the relation between the two is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using EntityFramework here.  Normally you would somehow relate those two things together and if one was a child of the other, you could just .Include() it and both would be hooked up.  If not, then you have to go manually load each instance and build up this Model you are returning yourself.  EF won't do it for you.  It won't be able to project those two separate entities the way you want.  The only way I think you could make it work would be a painful/chatty experience.  Also, if you leave it as IEnumerable or don't do .ToList(), the query doesn't run so if the context is killed below before it has a chance to run, you will also be in trouble.  Hopefully you can do this, but I don't know your model:

```
var result = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Cars>().Get().Include(a => a.Models).ToList();
return result.Select(a => new CarsModel { Car = a, Models = a.Models }).ToList();
```

If that doesn't work, then you need the more painful/slow way:

```
var cars = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Cars>().Get().ToList();
var result = new List<CarsModel>();
foreach (var car in cars) 
{
    result.Add(new CarsModel { Cars = car, Model = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Models>().Get(a => a.CardId == car.Id).ToList() });  // Assuming .Get() can take a filter

return result;
}
```